# Why hiding virtual functions behind non virtual equals

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have seen a pattern in code where you hide some of your virtual functions behind non virtual functions like this:

```cpp
class IApa {
   public:
   virtual ~IApa() = default;

   void update() {
      doUpdate();
   };

   private:
   virtual void doUpdate() = 0;
};

class Apa: public IApa {
   private:

   void doUpdate() override {...}
};
```

I know that it is some kind of code pattern, but to me it only looks like you pollute the interface. What is the reason for using a pattern like this?

It is also possible that the examples I have seen is implemented wrong, do you know any design pattern that is similar to this, and what is the motivation for doing it?

Comment: [Non Virtual Interface](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) idiom.  C++ can use a private virtual.  C# does not allow for private virtual (for some inexplicable reason; it's a useful access).  The public facing function should *not* be virtual, because it is used to enforce pre- and post-conditions (if any).  The idiom is not very useful for small projects; very helpful for large projects.

Comment: The reason is that `update` might, later, need to be changed to do something in addition to calling `do_update()`. This approach provides no-cost flexibility for future maintenance. It's done throughout the C++ standard library.

Comment: Original motivation: A `public virtual` function in an interface is declaring two things. "This is part of this class's public API" and "this is a customization point where child classes are expected to provide functionality". There's no fundamental reason to join these two declarations at the hip, and the NVI idiom is a way of making them independent.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes, its just that, as with pimpl, it comes at the cost of duplicating all virtual function declarations. For a codebase as the one I work in where the company can change all the code, If you wanted to have preconditions added, you could just convert the virtual function to a non virtual one (that does the preconditioning and calls the do_\*-function) and then recompile the codebase. If you apply all these idioms without thinking the codebase will instantly be twice the size without reason :/

Comment: It doesn't come close to doubling the size of the codebase. Each virtual function will correspond to one additional declaration and definition _in the abstract base class_, but you won't have any new functions in any of the concrete classes. Or are you saying that the codebase doubles in size without reason if you apply this idiom _and also_ a bunch of additional, unspecified, unjustified idioms?

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes